# How can I search content by tags?

Tags: 2010, search, tagging, social-tag

Can I get somehow all content (possibly in current scope only) with specified TAG(s) ?

I haven't found anything in search syntax, and such thing like `tag:pricing` does not return results tagged with tag **pricing**

Answer (score 1):

In order to use syntax like that you need to ensure that the "tag" property is a Managed Property in your search configuration. If it does not exist, you may first want to create it, map it to corresponding crawled property and perform a full crawl. After these steps are performed, try above syntax in search text box.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with SharePoint 2010 Search a bit, so there's a refiner on tags, it uses the `MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo,popularsocialtags"` Managed Property, so you should search like `ows_MetadataFacetInfo:pricing` or `popularsocialtags:pricing` instead of `tag:pricing` I think :)